# Seeding a subscribers data when it comes online after a publisher

Tags: distributed-computing, messaging, nservicebus, event-sourcing

Lets say we have two business components

1. **User management**

This owns users. When user information is changed this component publishes messages. So for example "NewUserCreated"

1. **Publications**

Handles correspondence with users. Email, tweets etc. So this component subscribes to the user messages stores a subset of that information in its own store.

#### The problem

What happens if the User Management component comes online before the Publications component? How does Publications get the list of existing users? It should not be aware of how the User management component stores its data.

Comment: Why does it need the list of users? How would it get the list of users if the publications service came up first?

Comment: Well that is really the question. how is the initial synchronisation performed?

Comment: That does not matter as long as you have the subscriptions available. You can also add subscriptions manually to the subscription database for the messages

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure User management and Publications are BCs, but rather different services, or ACs, because they serve different business functionality rather then two subsets of entities.

storing a subset of the User entity in the Publications service might be a service smell. There should be no data duplication whatsoever between the two services, except for the correlation id (userId).

The publication service does not need a list of all users:

If you're talking about short server downtime like maintenance or version updates, then messages sent from the UserManagement service will be available in the outgoing queue (or error queue after the configured timeout) and can be resent to the Publications service. Previous data should be in the Publications data store.

Let's think about another scenario - lets say that you had your system running for a year now, and you've been collecting user information all that time without the features in your publication service. Now, after you have millions of users, you add the new publication service.

Initially, there will be no data there. When a current user of the systems logs in - he might see a new page where he should fill in his publication details (email, twitter, facebook account etc.), this will cause a new entry in the publication service data (with the relevant userId). New users will add data to the publication service data store when they sign in (if you require them to do so).

Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

As with any integration project I would simply opt for an ETL procedure to get the relevant data you need before your new system starts up.

It is a once-off affair so no need to complicate matters :)

Answer (score 0):

As moranlf is saying, User management and Publications seem like two different services.
There should not be data duplication between the two.

Publications is like the Shipping Service in the well-known Amazon analogy: it holds data about the user entity (adresses), but only its own / the one it's responsible for (appart from the userId, which is common to both of them). Any event published from the User Management service would not "create" data into the Subscriptions Service. It might start a policy / saga, trigger a handler, but nothing more.

Two scenarios here:

- You already have the subscriptions stored in your data store and you're trying to split responsabilities into two separate services. Since the Publications service only holds its own data, it's just about moving data from one table/persistence store to another one. There is no need to replay or generate events.
- You don't have the subscriptions: there is nothing to do in this case, as it will store its data when the user takes action.

Does that help?